# ZF2 Doctrine Query With Multiple OR Conditions

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, mariadb

I've wrote the following Doctrine query:

```
        $query3 = $this->entityManager
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('t.textDomain , t.translationKey , t.languageIso , t.translationDate')
            ->from(
                'AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\TranslationsMasters',
                't'
            )
            ->groupBy('t.languageIso')
            ->orderBy(
                't.translationDate',
                'DESC'
            );

// the values of $key2 array are:
// en-US
// es-MX
// es-PR

        foreach( $translation AS $key2=>$value2 ) {               

            if ( $key2 == 'en-US' ) {

                $query3
                    ->orWhere(
                        $query3->expr()
                               ->like(
                                   't.languageIso',
                                   ':languageIso'
                               )
                    )
                    ->setParameter(
                        'languageIso',
                        $key2
                    );

            }

        }

        $result3 = $query3->getQuery()
                          ->getArrayResult();
```

How do I have the query search for all 3 language ISO's *at the same time*?

- With "if ( $key2 == 'en-US' ) {" the query executes and gives me the expected result.
- But if I remove "if ( $key2 == 'en-US' ) {" there are no search results.

I thought by using "orWhere" it would keep adding conditions to the query (where en-US will still produce a match).

Comment: Have you tried to call `getSQL()` instead of `getQuery()` to see the generated SQL query ?

orWhere seems to be capricious : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878448/doctrine-or-where

Comment: I've discovered my problem.  I used :languageIso.  The final bound language ISO was searched for in all instances.  A simply modification has resolved this:

Comment: $i = 1;
            foreach( $translation AS $key2=>$value2 ) {

                $query3
                    ->orWhere(
                        $query3->expr()
                               ->like(
                                   't.languageIso',
                                   ':languageIso'.$i
                               )
                    )
                    ->setParameter(
                        'languageIso'.$i,
                        $key2
                    );

            ++$i;
            }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In haven't ever been able to get `orWhere` to function the way I think it should.  It might be that you need a `Where` in your opening definition before you can add an `orWhere` later.  You might have to use the nested `orX` statement like this instead:

```
$query3->andWhere($query3->expr()->orX(
    $query3->expr()->like('t.languageIso', $query3->expr()->literal('en-US')),
    $query3->expr()->like('t.languageIso', $query3->expr()->literal('es-MX')),
    $query3->expr()->like('t.languageIso', $query3->expr()->literal('es-PR'))
));
```

You can't develop the statement through a loop.  But, since you've only got three criteria, it's easy enough to write out.