# Running Subquery in doctrine is not giving correct Result

Tags: sql, dql, symfony-2.8

sql

> WHERE  code= 'abc'  AND (column_name NOT IN ('436') or    column_name  is null)

Doctrine code

```
            ->innerJoin('Bundle:Web', 'p', 'WITH', 'b.pid= p.id')
            ->where('a.code= :cust_id')
            ->andWhere('p.column_name  NOT IN ( :id)')
            ->setParameter('id', array_keys($id)[0])
            ->orWhere('p.column_name  is null')
```

Running Dql gives different Result in Symfony2.

- any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: Your first query is `X AND (Y OR Z)` but your second query appears to be `X AND Y OR Z` which is the same as `(X AND Y) OR (Z)`.  This pattern appears to be common : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878448/doctrine-or-where

Comment: Thanks MAT i have solved this problem

Comment: should i post proper answer here

Comment: Yes, that would help people.

Answer (score 1):

solution that i tried

```
        ->innerJoin('Bundle:Web', 'p', 'WITH', 'b.pid= p.id')
        ->where('a.code= :cust_id')
        ->andWhere('p.column_name  NOT IN ( :id) or p.column_name  is null ')
        ->setParameter('id', array_keys($id)[0])
```

here in above dql it saves orWhere condition in dql.